# Problem while opening Qt

Tags: qt

> Cannot overwrite file /home/sauron/.config/QtProject/qtcreator/qtversion.xml: Permission denied.

Why does this message show up every time I open Qt?

Comment: serbest.exe will be running in the system monitor this might be causing  the issue. In this case please kill that from system monitor and open the Qt. Hope this will help.

Comment: Have run QtCreator with `sudo` before?

Answer (score 2):

You should have Read and Write permissions for yourself on `/home/sauron/.config/QtProject/qtcreator/qtversion.xml`.

Right-click the *qtversion.xml* file →  *Properties* → *Permissions* tab and change the permissions if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Through cleaner way, better to use `apt`:

```
sudo apt-get remove libqscintilla2-designer
```

Comment: Could you clarify how can this solve the problem?